# tikz curves with repetitive form

Tags: tikz-pgf, bezier

Could someone rewrite the code using tikz loop and cycle features to obtain the shape as attached at the bottom. Optionally, add your tricks to make the ends of the ribbon look more natural.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw [line width=1pt] foreach \x in {0,8}
     {(0+\x,0) .. controls (1+\x,.9) and (3+\x,-.3) .. (4+\x,0)
     .. controls (5+\x,.3) and (7+\x,-.9) .. (8+\x,0)};
    \draw[step=1cm] (0,-5) grid (16,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of clipping the path to remove the line ends we can create this by filling an area of that form.

For this we need to draw the path once to the right (but half your intended line width higher) and then back (but half your intended line width lower).
Since your path is symmetrical we can just simply rotate it.

We can do this with vanilla TikZ options:

```
\fill[red] (0,0)
  foreach \flip in {
    {shift=(up:.5cm)},
    {shift=(down:.5cm),rotate around={180:(right:8)}}
  } { [style/.expand once=\flip]
    -- (0,0) foreach \x in {0,8}{
      .. controls (1+\x,.9) and (3+\x,-.3) .. (4+\x,0)
      .. controls (5+\x,.3) and (7+\x,-.9) .. (8+\x,0)
    }
  } -- cycle;
```

[image]

Or we can use [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey)'s [`calligraphy` library](https://texdoc.org/serve/spath3/1) (`\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}`) which is based on his [`spath3` library](https://texdoc.org/serve/spath3/0):

```
\pen (up:.5cm) -- (down:.5cm);
\calligraphy[pen colour=red] (0,0)
  foreach \x in {0,8}{
    .. controls (1+\x,.9) and (3+\x,-.3) .. (4+\x,0)
    .. controls (5+\x,.3) and (7+\x,-.9) .. (8+\x,0)
  };
```

[image]

You can do all sort of things that way:

```
\pen (up:.2cm) -- (down:.2cm) (up:.4cm) (down:.4cm);
\calligraphy[pen colour=red, light] (0,0)
  foreach \x in {0,8}{
    .. controls (1+\x,.9) and (3+\x,-.3) .. (4+\x,0)
    .. controls (5+\x,.3) and (7+\x,-.9) .. (8+\x,0)
  };
\pen (0,0);
\calligraphy[pen colour=orange, heavy] (0,0)
  foreach \x in {0,8}{
    .. controls (1+\x,.9) and (3+\x,-.3) .. (4+\x,0)
    .. controls (5+\x,.3) and (7+\x,-.9) .. (8+\x,0)
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, fantastic solutions. I was working on it but didn't come with something acceptable enough. +1

Comment: @SebGlav I'm stupid, we could just use Andrew's `calligraphy` library right away. (See edit.)

Comment: Err, indeed... the simplest thing is not always what comes up first in mind.

Comment: is it possible to add a random parameter for the bézier curves?

Comment: @user1850133 Sure, TikZ (or rather its underlying mathematical engine) provides various pseudo-random functions: `rnd` (between `0` and `1`), `rand` (between `-1` and `1`) and `random(x,y)` (integer between `x` and `y`). Though, you probably want to store that random number so that you can reuse since the ending curve's control point should lie opposite the starting curve's control point.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, it's already a seamless loop in your code. You can make use of tikz syntax to iterate over the desired step with specifying a set `{0,8,...,24}` for example.

In order to make ends of the ribbon look like on your screenshot, you can simply crop it from both sides.

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\iterations{5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ribbonLength}{\iterations*8}

    \clip (1,-5) rectangle (\ribbonLength,5);

     \draw [red, line width=20pt] foreach \x in {0,8,...,\ribbonLength}
     {(0+\x,0) .. controls (1+\x,.9) and (3+\x,-.3) .. (4+\x,0)
     .. controls (5+\x,.3) and (7+\x,-.9) .. (8+\x,0)};
    
    \draw[step=1cm] (0,-5) grid (16,5);
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Simply change the `\iterations` variable to specify the amount of repetition.